# Language-wise typography quotes

Tags: django, typography

Has anyone ever encountered Django template filters to transform "straight quotes" into typographically correct equivalents in given language, for example „Polish” or «Russian» ones?

Comment: Have you checked out the "local flavor" documentation? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/localflavor/#module-django.contrib.localflavor

I would also recommend looking through the "Format localization" documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/formatting/

Comment: Yes, I have, and from what I've seen it's not even near—“local favor” concentrates on adding country-specific fields and has nothing to do with typography; “format localization” works on dates, times, numbers etc., doesn't change quotes.

[Django-typogrify](https://github.com/chrisdrackett/django-typogrify) would be closer, but it works only with standard English quotes.

Comment: Fork Django-typogrify (or smartypants.py) and add functionality to do just this? For simplicity, for starters you could write simple functions like 'toPolishQuotes' or 'toRussianQuotes'. But for more comprehensiveness, you'd have a table of quote styles and permutations (guillemets, Polish style etc.) and map them languages/locales?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like a filter to do this exists - you'll need to write one yourself. [Smartypants](http://web.chad.org/projects/smartypants.py/) can help you do it for english quotes, but I'm not sure what you'd use for the others.